# Deployed laravel website can't upload image

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, cpanel

I just deployed my laravel website. It works but when i try to add image in the web, error comes out. I think it has something to do with the document root in Cpanel being 'public_html' while the local file was 'public'. Thanks in advance.

**Error**
 Can't write image data to path (/home/stalwart/sty/public/img/members/1566132567.jpeg)

**Controller**

```
\Image::make($request->filename)->save(public_path('img/members/').$name);
```

Comment: Did you check the folder permission?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem but with a Railway deployment via github. Changing folder permissions seems a plausible solution, but the thing is that I don't understand how the permissions are set in this type of deployments. How could I change that?

Answer (score 0):

A more elaborate description of the error you are facing would have been better.

However, my best thought is that it might be an issue to do with permissions. We have it at 755 and write access for group and world is not allowed.
[Checkout this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvIqA.png)

Unless you give write access to users of your site I don't think they will be able to upload images.

A much more precise description of your problem would make it easier to solve or at least try.